# Photos of Children Without Permission

Tags: public-domain

In a public coffee shop I sat next to a photographer who, without their knowledge or permission, photographed women and children from the waist down as they stood at the cashier station. I notified the acting store manager, who knows this customer and says he is a professional photographer. She was not aware he was doing this. Is it legal for the photographer to photograph children from the waist down without parental permission?

Comment: This isn't a question that can be answered by photographers. It's one you need to ask a lawyer or a policeman about. You didn't even tell us where in the world you are.

Comment: Are you in France? Dubai? Sri Lanka? etc? The answer can vary greatly by location. But perhaps the greatest concern is that the question addresses what is or is not *legal* without a hint of concern over whether something that is legal may have *ethical* issues.

Comment: @Tetsujin Policemen don't know... I keep a copy of the French law about this in my bag because most people, including policemen, think it is much more restrictive than it really is. In the case at hand, the shooting is in a private place (opened to the public, but still privately owned) it is possibly at the management's discretion but the customers have the choice to go elsewhere. There is also a difference being taking the picture and publishing it.

Comment: Bizarrely, it was until only a couple of weeks ago in the UK, perfectly legal to take furtive 'upskirt' photos. It was [of course] frowned upon for long before that, but wasn't strictly 'illegal'... so I'm back to "the lawyer/policeman for whatever country you live in".

Comment: 2years and 60K€ in France :)

Comment: This is a question for law enforcement, not photographers.

Comment: Voting to close and flagging to move to legal.se. Should it move, you need to edit in a jurisdiction to get any sort of answer.